# What does this error message in python mean?

Tags: python

I am making a hangman game on python and when i try to run it this error message appears. If anyone could tell me what this means i would be grateful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Computing\Unit 3\Hangman\hangmanv2.py", line 200, in <module>
    hangmangame()
  File "D:\Computing\Unit 3\Hangman\hangmanv2.py", line 195, in hangmangame
    newwords()
  File "D:\Computing\Unit 3\Hangman\hangmanv2.py", line 187, in newwords
    hangmangame()
  File "D:\Computing\Unit 3\Hangman\hangmanv2.py", line 158, in hangmangame
    guessletter()
  File "D:\Computing\Unit 3\Hangman\hangmanv2.py", line 136, in guessletter
    print(hangmanpics[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your list `hangmanpics` is empty.

If `hangmanpics[0]` is giving you an `IndexError`, then it means that no element exists at the 0<sup>th</sup> index, which being the first index, implies that your list is empty.

Answer (score 4):

The error means that the (zero) index in `hangmanpics[0]` is out of range. In other words, `hangmanpics` is an empty list.

Try printing it out to verify.